# Column space and subspace - $R^m$ and $R^n$

Tags: matrices

The statement is:
The set of all solutions of a system of $m$ homogeneous equations in $n$ unknowns is a subspace of $R^n$.

I said this statement must be false because the set of all solutions of a system is the column space and by definition the column space of A is the subspace of $R^m$.

Why is the correct answer true? Does "the set of all solutions" not refer to the column space? Is my understanding of the definition wrong?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "set of all solutions of a system is the column space"?

Comment: @BenGrossmann I thought that column space describes the space any solution exists after the transformation (for Ax = b any possible b output would be the column space according to my understanding)

Comment: There's no matrix $A$ mentioned in the statement. So what is the relationship between the statement and the matrix $A$ whose column-space you're discussing?

Comment: In fact, if a homogeneous system is written in the form $Ax = 0$, the solution space to this system is the set of vectors $x$ (input-vectors) that result in an output $Ax$ of $0$.

Comment: so is it correct to say that any set of vectors $x$ that result in an output of 0 must be in the null space? (if we assume x is not the zero-vector)

Comment: It is correct that any vector $x$ that results in an output of $0$ is in the nullspace, **even if** $x$ is the zero vector. This property is exactly what defines the nullspace.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the equation $$Ax=b,$$ the set of solutions $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ for a fixed $b$ is an *affine* subspace of $R^n$. But the solution(s) only exist if $b$ is in the column space of $A$, which is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$.

If $b=0$ ($0$ is always in the column space of $A$) the set of solutions correspond to the null space of matrix $A$, which is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.